# how to make pinch/zoom work on an image

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, zooming, pinch

I am still learning the tricks to jQuery mobile and have been having a problem with the zooming in and zooming out of a picture/image on a data-role="page." Is there a way to make the pinch/zoom work on an image on the iPhone using jquery mobile?  Cant get it to work on the iOS Simulator. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>

<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2" name="viewport">

<link href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- This reference to phonegap.js will allow for code hints as long as the current site     has been configured as a mobile application. 
To configure the site as a mobile application, go to Site -> Mobile Applications ->     Configure Application Framework... -->
<script src="/phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="padding:0;">    
           <img src="coffee.gif" width="320" height="480" alt="coffee">
        </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
   </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for your help.  Much appreciated.

-bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the viewport metadata property that controls those settings.

[Follow this](http://chillburn.com.au/blog/enabling-the-pinch-zoom-for-the-ipad-iphone-while-using-jquery-mobile/) to see how to enable pinch & zoom on JQM iOS (shouldn't really matter that you are using PhoneGap).

Hope this helps.

> When jQuery Mobile renders a page, it adds the following meta tag to
>   the head of the document.

```
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

> It is the minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 part of
>   the tag which disables the pinch zoom. What we need to do is modify
>   the $.mobile.metaViewportContent variable. We can do this using the
>   following code.

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){ 
    $.mobile.metaViewportContent = 'width=device-width'; 
});
```

> If we want to restrict the amount of zooming, we can use the following:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){ 
    $.mobile.metaViewportContent = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2'; 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

edit the "viewport" in meta tag with this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.5, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```